# Can I have iOS Automation shortcuts run automatically?

Tags: ios, shortcut, airpods, shortcuts-app

I've been having a problem where sometimes I'll forget that my iPhone's volume is set pretty high from a previous use. When I put my AirPods in for a phone call or to listen to music, the volume isn't automatically lowered to a reasonable level. Instead, loud, ear-damaging noise blasts through my AirPods when the call starts or the music plays, and I often have to quickly take them out.

I tried to resolve this by using the new Automation feature in Shortcuts. I created an automation that uses the Bluetooth trigger to run whenever my phone connects to my AirPods. When this happens, it sets the volume to 30%.

So far, so good.

But when I actually use my AirPods, all I get is a notification from Shortcuts giving me the option of running the script (see below).

The little popup is actually kind of irritating - I want Shortcuts to just silently fix the volume without prompting me.

[image]

Is it possible to have the Automation feature **automatically** run the script when the trigger occurs?

Comment: God forbid there’s an option to “expose me to security risk by having volume change”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: This has improved with iOS 14:
In iOS 14, Turn off "Ask Before Running" to avoid getting a notification and have automations run automatically in the background. See full list at See https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios

---

Not all triggers can make an automation run in the background.

> When you Arrive, Leave, connect to CarPlay, or use the Before I Leave or Time of Day triggers, or try to automate connecting to Wi-Fi or Bluetooth, your shortcuts will only show up as notifications and won't run in the background. These are the only triggers where a user may not be in control of their device or it's state, and thus seem to be limited for security reasons – all other triggers can run in the background.

https://imore.com/whats-new-siri-shortcuts-betas.  See under "Personal automation". It's a long page, so cmd + F.

https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios

Answer (score 1):

When you set up the automation, before you click „Done“, there should be a toggle called „Ask Before Running“. Switch that to off and it should run in the background.

Comment: Hmm I don’t see that setting. I even tried recreating the automation. Could you send a screenshot?

Comment: Okay, here's the issue: bluetooth triggers can't be run automatically: https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/enable-or-disable-a-personal-automation-apd602971e63/ios

Comment: Bill, thanks so much for posting the info about Bluetooth triggers. <strike>I wanted to automatically put my iPhone in full Airplane mode (including Wifi and Bluetooth) at midnight but apparently I won't be able to. Saved me updating to iOS 15 which I don't want to do.</strike> Turns out that Time of Day will run without notifications on iOS 14+ and will turn off Bluetooth, Wifi and turn on Airplane Mode. Finally have a reason to update from iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Autocuts for this

https://adamtow.github.io/autocuts-admin/

Comment: Any other iOS native solutions for this yet?